# How to loop in a list more times than the list size?

Tags: python, list, loops

Is there a function or native lib in Python that allows me to loop in a list more times than the number of elements in the list? In other words, when my index of interest is greater than the list size, the next element is the first of the list.

For example, I have this list:

```
abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

So, if I have an index with value `10`, the result will be `'a'`. If the index is with value `18`, the result will be `'d'`.

Comment: Use the modulo operator.

Comment: You can create infinite sequence from you `abc` array with the function `cycle(seq)` from `itertools` module and then you can cut this sequence at some point with `islice(seq, count)` function from the same module.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simplest: wrap the index with modulo

```
>>> abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]
>>> abc[18 % len(abc)]
'd'
```

You can wrap it up in a helper class if you want:

```
>>> class ModList(list):
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         if isinstance(item, slice):
...             return super().__getitem__(item)
...         return super().__getitem__(item % len(self))
...     
>>> abc = ModList('abcde')
>>> abc[18]
'd'
>>> abc[-5]
'a'
>>> abc[-6]
'e'
```

You might want to implement `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` similarly.

Comment: what about abc[18:20]? :P

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.cycle()` works if you want to iterate sequentially, repeatedly through the list

```
from itertools import cycle


abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]

alfs = ''

for n, e in enumerate(cycle(abc)):  # lazy enumeration?
    alfs += e
    if n >= 18:  # must have stopping test to break infinite loop
        break
alfs
Out[30]: 'abcdeabcdeabcdeabcd'
```